# Meaning of くれる in 転がってくれるわ

Tags: meaning

I found the sentence: ようし、転がってくれるわ！
It was translated as: Alright, I'm gonna roll around! (The context is that the character is rolling on a soft tatami, he's alone so he's not really talking to anyone, just to himself.)

I know that くれる means to give, but since in this sentence no one is receiving anything, what is its meaning?

Comment: I think it may help if you familiarize yourself with favor giving/receiving subsidiary verbs first. This is a good place to start: https://www.guidetojapanese.org/favor.html

Comment: どういうキャラでしたか？特に口調が知りたいと思います。

Answer (score 3):

Verb + [くれる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/#jn-64758) can mean

> ㋐人が自分に、または自分の側の者に対して何かをすることを表す。「手伝って―・れる」「秘密にしておいて―・れ」「母がセーターを編んで―・れる」
>
> ㋑こちらが、相手に不利益になるようなことを与えることを表す。「痛い目にあわせて―・れるぞ」

Roughly it means the subject does V as favor or as something causing harm to the listener. In your example, I guess  the speaker is just saying either *I will give you the honor of my rolling around here* or *I will do harm by rolling around here*. Not really that these are seriously meant, but more of a joke.